# copy html div in javascript variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my aspx page i have a div which contains simple html ,has some id(say 'datadiv')

using jquery i want to get the html of that div (entire div) into a JavaScript variable

how can it be done?

thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var someVar = $("#somediv").html();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the equivalent of Internet Explorer's outerHTML to retrieve both the div and it's contents then the [function from this page](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/) that extends JQuery should help:#

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $('<div>').append( this.eq(0).clone() ).html();
};
```

Then call:

var html = $('#datadiv').outerHTML();

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <b>Hello</b><p>, how are you?</p>

            <script>
            $("b").clone().prependTo("p");
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
            **Out put:**
            Hello
            Hello, how are you?
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working..!! the simplest way !!
 HTML Code

```
<div class="extra-div">
    <div class="div-to-pull-in-variable">
     // Your Content Here
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Code

```
    $(function() {
        var completeDiv = $('.extra-div').html();
        alert(completeDiv); 
       })
    });
```